# Olympiad problem on the prime numbers

Tags: number-theory

> Let $P={2,3,5,7,11,...}$ denote the set of all prime numbers less than ${ 2 }^{ 100}$.
>
> Prove that $\sum _{ p\in P }^{  }{ \frac { 1 }{ p }  } < 8$.

I don't understand how to progress in the problem. Any help would appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What can you use? If you can use Mertens' second theorem, that does it.

Comment: I can't see how you can control the $o(1)$ ?

Comment: @DanielFischer,If you can't find an elementary solution, I would surely encourage you to post a solution using Merten's second theorem.

Comment: You need bounds on the difference, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens'_theorems) Mertens's (sufficient) bounds are given.

Comment: Considering that Mertens' theorem shows the sum is smaller than $5$, there should be a more elementary way that gives you a bound of $8$. But I don't see it immediately.

Comment: Seeing first two answers to this problem, I recall that philosophy of  Olympic problems discards high level of mathematical reasoning. Therefore, some bright teenager has solved this problem without using non elementary theorems.

Comment: @Ataulfo Agreed.I wonder who he is, but also how was his approach to this very problem.

Comment: A point to note is that it comes from a set of problems from the Junior Mathematical Olympiad.

Comment: @SwapnilDas: Wonderful if you get an answer given in the context of Olympics and the name of this (these?) bright teenager (s).

Comment: Starting with $H_{2^{100}} \sim 70$ and subtracting terms where $n$ is divisible by any of the first four primes $\{2,3,5,7\}$ using inclusion-exclusion we can bound the sum to $\lesssim 16$ using only the fact that $H_n \sim \log(n)$ which is not too bad but not quite there. It's not really feasible to push this method further by adding more primes to the list as the number of terms we need to compute just becomes too large.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rosser and Schoenfeld in [Approximate formulas for some functions of prime numbers](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1255631807) give an explicit form of Mertens' second theorem, an upper bound valid for all $x>1$:
$$
\sum_{p\le x} \frac1p < \log \log x + B + \frac1{\log^2x}
$$
where $B \approx 0.26149\cdots$.
This gives
$$
\sum_{p\le 2^{100}} \frac1p < 4.51 < 8
$$
However, this argument is most probably not in the spirit of the question.

Comment: On the other hand, this is the right kind of argument. No need (for me) to find a different proof.

Answer (score 3):

The problem can be easily solved if you can use the following bound on prime counting function $\pi(n)$ (taken from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function#Inequalities)):
$$\pi(n) / \frac{n}{\ln{n}} \le C = 1.25506$$

Rewrite you sum via $\pi(n)$:
$$
  \sum_{p \in P} \frac{1}{p} = \sum_{k=1}^{2^{100}}\frac{\pi(k) - \pi(k-1)}{k}
$$

Now use [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts), with $k$ starting from $a > 1$:
$$
  \sum_{k=a}^{2^{100}}\frac{\pi(k) - \pi(k-1)}{k} = 
  \left[ \frac{\pi(2^{100})}{2^{100} + 1} - \frac{\pi(a-1)}{a} \right] - \sum_{k=a}^{2^{100}}\pi(k)\left(\frac{1}{k+1} - \frac{1}{k}\right)
$$
Forget about the part in brackets, it should be easy to bound efficiently.
The sum in the main part can be bounded:
$$
  -\sum_{k=a}^{2^{100}}\pi(k)\left(\frac{1}{k+1} - \frac{1}{k}\right) = 
  \sum_{k=a}^{2^{100}}\frac{\pi(k)}{k(k+1)} \le
  \sum_{k=a}^{2^{100}}\frac{C \; k}{k(k+1)\ln{k}} \le 
  C \sum_{k=a}^{2^{100}}\frac{1}{k\ln{k}}
$$
We can bound this sum via integration. Define function $f(x) = (x \ln x)^{-1}$. It monotonically decreases for $x > 1$, so $(k \ln k)^{-1} \le \int_{k-1}^{k} f(x) dx$. Hence:
$$
  \sum_{k=a}^{2^{100}}\frac{1}{k\ln{k}} \le
  \int\limits_{a-1}^{2^{100}-1} \frac{dx}{x \ln x} = 
  \ln \ln x \bigg\rvert_{a-1}^{2^{100}-1} \le \ln \ln 2^{100} = 4.23865\ldots
$$
Multiplying this value by $C$ given above, we get a bound $5.32 < 8$. However, we also have to add the part in the brackets and the original sum for $k < a$.

Comment: If you're going to use the paper by Rosser and Schoenfeld (which is what Wikipedia cites), you may as well use their estimates for $\sum 1/p$, as I have done.

Comment: @lhf: You are right, it is from the same paper. Sorry, I didn't pay attention to the source of the bound... I thought prime number theorem is quite well-known, so there should be some proved upper bound on the constant.

Comment: @stgatilov It's nice.I wonder what my friends would say if they watch me answering this question in terms of the prime number theorem.Can you think of a more elementary solution, as per the olympiads?( BTW, I'm a ninth grader).